# Import data from xml

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm trying to get data from an XML file using simple_xml , so far I can get all the data except the images . How can I call a single image name ?

```
<?php

$ur="http://services2.jupix.co.uk/api/get_properties.php?clientID=35871cc1b6d9ec6237aaaf94aa0e0836&passphrase=cvYG9f";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($ur);

foreach ($xml->property as $property):

var_dump($property->images->image);
```

echo 'images->image">'; // this is not displaying

```
 endforeach;?>
```

My code output as the image below . How can i display image number 1
  public 1 => string 'http://media2.jupix.co.uk/v3/clients/657/properties/1356/IMG_1356_9_large.jpg' (length=77)

[image]

Comment: it is way easier to help you if you provide a nice minimum valid XML sample, instead of an image. so `echo $ur`, minimize it, then edit your question and add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Guy I found solution to my problem . 
Looking at the back at the question it seems I did not put it in a proper way 
All i wanted is to display images within that section. Xpath was not necessary But i have  learned from it . Here is my solution if you can improve it you are much welcome.

```
   $url ="http://services2.jupix.co.uk/api/get_properties.php?clientID=35871cc1b6d9ec6237aaaf94aa0e0836&passphrase=cvYG9f";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
foreach ($xml->property as $property):
?>
    <li>
    <h3> <?php echo $property->addressStreet;?> </h3>

        <?php 
$imgCount = count($property->images->image);
    for ($i=0; $i < $imgCount; $i++) { ?>    

 <img src="<?php echo $property->images->image[$i];?>">     

        <?php } ?>
        <p><?php echo  limit_text($property->fullDescription,30);?></p>
          <h4>&pound; <?php echo $property->price;?> </h4>
    </li>
        <?php  endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [SimpleXMLElement::xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) can do what you are looking for:

You can give this a try:

```
<?php
$ur="http://services2.jupix.co.uk/api/get_properties.php?clientID=35871cc1b6d9ec6237aaaf94aa0e0836&passphrase=cvYG9f";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($ur);
$image = $xml->xpath('//property/images/image[@modified="2014-07-23 14:22:05"]')[1]->__toString();
var_dump($image);
```

Or you can loop through all the images and check for the name the you are looking for:

```
$images = $xml->xpath('//property/images/image');

foreach ($images as $image) {
    $url = $image->__toString();
    if (false !== strpos($url, "_9_large.jpg")) {
        var_dump($url);
    }
}
```

If you want to get the second image of each /images section, then you could do it like this:

```
$images = $xml->xpath('//property/images');
foreach ($images as $image) {
    if (isset($image->children()[1])) {
        var_dump($image->children()[1]->__toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: This could be the right answer  if i knew the result of modified and also this is in a foreach loop . I was thinking of  $result = $xml->xpath('//property/images/image[@modified="'.$property->images->image[0].'"]')[1]->__toString();  But its not working

Comment: I've added another example where you can loop through all the images and filter for the one that you are looking for.

Comment: So if I am not mistaken you want to get the second image from each /images section?
I case you do, I've added another example for that.

Comment: Thanks for you help i will try this later